# A Transylvanian Hungarian MC Problem.

Tags: geometry, inequality, analytic-geometry, slope

**question**

Show that there exist infinitely many non similar triangles such that the side-lengths are positive integers and the areas of squares constructed on their sides are in arithmetic progression.

**Solution**

let the sides be $a,b,c$ ,
let $a \ge b\ge c$
so , we have $a^2+c^2=2b^2$. put $a/b=x ,c/b=y, x,y>0$
so , we get $x^2+y^2=2$....(*) ,
with $x,y\in Q, x,y>0$
now , consider a particular solution $(p,q)$.
consider the slope (k) of the line joining $(p,q)$ & $(x,y)$.
$k=\frac{y-q}{x-p}$ , now express $y$ in terms of $k,p,q$ and put that in (*). then appying Vieta's relation , we can easily solve the problem.we must keep in mind the problem conditions for choosing $k$ carefully.
a such set of solution is given by $(a,b,c)=(k^2-1+2k,k^2+1,k^2-2k-1)$. ---------(###)
we must choose $k\in N , [k\ge5] $ carefully  such that , they are consistent with the problem condition.
it is quite obvious that , we can make infinitely many non-similar triangles satisfying the condition from this family with suitable values of $k$
[the proof of the last sentence is trivial ,so i am not posting it. it uses basic divisibility and triangle inequality

**Source**

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h464522p2602940

**Doubt**

Please some body explain  how vieta relation apply here and how the equation -----------(###) comes And why $k\in N , [k\ge5] $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution hints at a general method to solve an equation like $$x^2+y^2=2 \tag{1}$$
for rational $x$ and $y$, but the explanation is not so clear.

The trick is that of choosing a particular solution $(p,q)$, for instance $(1,-1)$, and parameterise all  other solutions $(x,y)$ by the slope $k$ of the line through $(1,-1)$ and $(x,y)$, which is a rational number. The equation of that line is
$$
y+1=k(x-1),
\quad\text{that is}\quad
y=kx-k-1.
$$
Substituting this into $(1)$ gives
$$
(1+k^2)x^2-2k(k+1)x+k^2+2k-1=0
$$
and factoring out the solution $x=1$ (or using Vieta's rule for the product of roots) we are left with
$$
x={k^2+2k-1\over1+k^2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
y={k^2-2k-1\over1+k^2}.
$$
For the purpose of the given exercise you can simply take integer values of $k$, with $k\ge3$ (not $5$) to get positive solutions. But for a more general solution you may want to substitute $k=m/n$ and express $a$, $b$, $c$ as a function of integers $m$ and $n$.